# How to implement virus scanning for Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, antivirus, bho

I need to write a tool that performs an operation (like virus scanning but more heuristic) on each file downloaded by IE (so those for which the "Save" dialog pops up).

The problem is that I have no clue where to start on this; I've read a little about BHO, but since I have no experience with COM, I'd like a working example (or some tutorial for complete noobs). Or maybe a different approach is possible?

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[APIs used by Microsoft Windows Defender](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914922)